# Implementing custom compareTo

Tags: java, compareto

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Object t) 
{
    if(t instanceof Student)
    {
        Student s = (Student)t;
        return (this.name.compareTo(s.name));
    }
    else
        return -1;
}
```

This is my `compareTo` method implementation for comparing two `Student` objects based on their name. Is it possible to compare two such objects based on multiple fields i.e., both name and age?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible to compare two objects based on different sort sequences using `Comparator` interface `compare` method.

You need to create a sort sequence class. [Sorting user defined objects using comparator](http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/06/17/sorting-user-defined-objects-part-2/)

Comment: Can you also tell me the difference between `Collections.sort()` and getting a sorted collection by adding into a `TreeSet`?

Comment: @AnjanBaradwaj, I feel, instead of providing a vague answer, I would like you to ask this question on SO, of course with some efforts and code and we both will learn about it from experts :)

Answer (score 16):

Yes, but first you should type the Comparable interface you're implementing. Here's what it should look like:

```
public class Student implements Comparable<Student> {
    private int age;
    private String name;
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Student s) {
        if (name.equals(s.name))
            return age - s.age;
        return name.compareTo(s.name));
    }
}
```

Notice how with the typed interface `Comparable<Student>`, instead of the raw type `Comparable`, there's no need to cast.

Comment: It is considered poor style, because it us "unsafe" (unless you use `instanceof`, which is also poor style), but it's completely unnecessary in this case if you correctly type this class, which is *good* style. Your code should use as narrow typing as it can.

Comment: Warning! The code above works well, because age is not supposed to be a negative value. 
But be careful when negative values ​​are possible. 
Do not take the above code as the canonical way to implement Comparable<T> (natural ordering)

Comment: @FernandoPelliccioni actually, this code works perfectly for negative values of age (you can verify this yourself using pen and paper). The only vulnerability introduced by allowing negative numbers is numeric overflow, but to be a problem it requires values in the billions - a situation that is reasonable to ignore for such dara.

Comment: @Bohemian, you're right, I did wrong calculations. Sorry for the noise.
However, we should not consider this code as the standard way of writing comparators for integral types.

Comment: Name is being compared twice. I would prefer:

int result = name.compareTo(s.name);
if(result==0) return age - s.age;
else return result;

Answer (score 1):

Note that you are [overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9598166/java-method-overloading/9598409#9598409) the `compareTo` method in your above code, not overriding it.

The `interface` you are implementing:

```
public interface Comparable<T> {
    public int compareTo(T o);
}
```

Your implementation:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Object t) {
    //...
}
```

The original author of this interface, Josh Bloch, advised in his book [Effective Java](http://uet.vnu.edu.vn/~chauttm/e-books/java/Effective.Java.2nd.Edition.May.2008.3000th.Release.pdf) to use the `@Override` annotation just for this reason; bugs caused by overloading can be rather hard to spot.

You say you want to compare these objects "based on multiple fields"- I'm not sure if this means "order them one way based on two fields" or "order them multiple ways, each based on a single field". Either are possible, as demonstrated in the other answers here.

However, this is the bottom line:

You should implement `Comparable<T>` if you are creating a class yourself, as you appear to be, and want to define a "natural ordering" for this class. If you want to define multiple orderings or you do not control the class in question, define your own ordering in a class that implements `Comparator<T>` (See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)).

Answer (score 1):

Apache [CompareToBuilder](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/CompareToBuilder.html) class is worth a mention.

You can implement with or without reflection

```
public int compareTo(Object o) {
    return CompareToBuilder.reflectionCompare(this, o);
}
```