# javax.json: Add new JsonNumber to existing JsonObject

Tags: java, json

I want to add properties to an existing instance of `JsonObject`. If this property is `boolean`, this is quite easy:

```
JsonObject jo = ....;
jo.put("booleanProperty", JsonValue.TRUE);
```

However, I also want to add a `JsonNumber` but I couldn't find a way to create an instance of `JsonNumber`. Here's what I could do:

```
JsonObjectBuilder job = Json.createObjectBuilder();
JsonNumber jn = job.add("number", 42).build().getJsonNumber("number");
jo.put("numberProperty", jn);
```

But I couldn't think of a more dirty way to accomplish my task. So - is there are more direct, cleaner approach to add a `JsonNumber` to an existing instance of `JsonObject`?

Comment: Note that you should specify which JSON kit you're using.  What you want to do is trivial in several of them.

Comment: As said in the title, I'm using javax.json. Although this is a high-level set of interfaces and factory classes only and implementations are somewhat independent from that, the answer stays the same: When using javax.json, it's not possible.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Okay, I just figured it out myself: **You can't**.

`JsonObject` is supposed to be immutable. Even if `JsonObject.put(key, value)` exists, at runtime this will throw an `UnsupportedOperationException`. So if you want to add a key/value-pair to an existing `JsonObject` you'll need something like

```
private JsonObjectBuilder jsonObjectToBuilder(JsonObject jo) {
    JsonObjectBuilder job = Json.createObjectBuilder();

    for (Entry<String, JsonValue> entry : jo.entrySet()) {
        job.add(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }

    return job;
}
```

and then use it with

```
JsonObject jo = ...;
jo = jsonObjectToBuilder(jo).add("numberProperty", 42).build();
```

Comment: What if value wasn't 42? I have same problem and I try to: jo = jsonObjectToBuilder(jo).add(String, Object).build(); and it asks JsonValue. Because I try to create dynamic method which values can be String, Integer etc. What should I do?

Comment: You're runing into a more general Java problem here. When using overloaded methods, the method that is used must be resolved at compile time. If you're using an instance of `Object`, then that can't be resolved at compile time, because it could be a `String` or a `JsonValue` in the end. The correct solution is probably to create overloaded methods yourself, which accept the various data types also supported by `JsonObjectBuilder.add`, and passes them there. Explanation of overloaded methods: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9598166/java-method-overloading

Answer (score 7):

Try using JsonPatch

```
String json ="{\"name\":\"John\"}";
JsonObject jo = Json.createReader(new StringReader(json)).readObject();
JsonPatch patch = Json.createPatchBuilder()
        .add("/last","Doe")
        .build();
jo = patch.apply(jo);
System.out.println(jo);
```

Answer (score 5):

JsonObject is immutable but can be copied into a JsonObjecBuilder using lambdas.

```
JsonObject source = ...
JsonObjectBuilder target = Json.createObjectBuilder();
source.forEach(target::add); // copy source into target
target.add("name", "value"); // add or update values
JsonObject destination = target.build(); // build destination
```

Comment: so nice, makes me hesitate using JsonPatch now :-)