# Which one to use? JSONObject from org.json VS JsonObject from javax.json

Tags: java, android, json

This is my first post. As a budding Android developer, I read SO posts on a near daily basis on various topics, but for this question, I didn't find any help from Google or SO.

My research so far:
Searching for this question was harder than normal because the search engines don't seem to care about case-sensitivity, which is vital in this issue. Searching Google only gave me links to the classes themselves, old articles, or completely irrelevant articles. The closest I got was JSONArray vs JSONObject, and that is a completely different question. SO searching gave the same results. As far as I can tell, ALL pertinent posts on SO refer to JSONObject and not JsonObject.

Neither Oracle nor json.org documentation mentioned the other side, nor did the Android developer JSONObject page which uses the org.json library.

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonObject.html
http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html
I would have also posted a link to the Android reference page for JSONObject, but my rep as a newbie is too low.

History of problem(s):
I was reading about Json encoding and decoding from the Oracle page, and I tried copying and pasting into my AndriodStudio IDE, which immediately produced an error, for which it did not suggest an import statement like it normally does. I have come to learn that means the class is not part of the built-in libraries.

The problem was that the code I pasted in used JsonObject (which comes from javax.json library) and not JSONObject (which comes from org.json library). When I noticed the difference in case between the Android page and the Oracle page, I altered my code from Json to JSON and immediately my IDE offered the org.json import statement.

Question(s):
Why is an Oracle made class not part of the default libraries when an external library is?
Is JSON the old, deprecated way and Json the new, proper way?
Are they functionally identical? If not, please provide examples?
Are some situations better for one and some better for the other?
ULTIMATELY, which should I use, and why (if not already covered)?
If, javax.json, where is the best (safest) place to download that library)?

Comment: _the default libraries_ The JDK you use for developing on Android is provided by Android, not Oracle. Also `javax.json` is part of Java EE, not Java SE.

Comment: I didn't download an additional jdk when I moved from straight Java to Android. Is the alternate JDK included in the AndroidStudio application?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Bit late, but I wanted to share my opinion on this.

I faced this problem recently when I found a Java project with both libraries and they were used at the same time.

I think that `org.json` is easier to read and to use, for 2 main reasons (for my needs):

1. JsonObject is immutable. You can't add new key/value pairs to an already existing JsonObject (reference here: [javax.json: Add new JsonNumber to existing JsonObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26346060/javax-json-add-new-jsonnumber-to-existing-jsonobject))
2. It takes a few lines to pretty print a JsonObject or JsonArray, while it only takes 1 line to do it with JSONObject or JSONArray. Example:

   ```
   StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
   Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
   properties.put(JsonGenerator.PRETTY_PRINTING, true);

   JsonWriterFactory writerFactory = Json.createWriterFactory(properties);
   JsonWriter jsonWriter = writerFactory.createWriter(sw);

   jsonWriter.writeObject(jsonObject); //JsonObject created before
   jsonWriter.close();
   String prettyPrintedJSON = sw.toString();
   ```

That is the code I use to get an indented JSON to write to a file. And with org.json I only need `jsonObject.toString(4)`.

Another difference is the constructors. You will need a `JsonObjectBuilder` to create a JSON with `javax.json`. One step more that can be avoided.

I'm sure there are more differences (not sure if it's possible to create a  `JsonObject` from a String) but these are my thoughts.

Comment: It should be noted that javax.json makes full use of the existing interfaces while org.json works with no interfaces at all, so e.g. a JSONArray cannot be used in an foreach block. org.json may be made more practical, but not using the existing interfaces could be seen as a design flaw.

Comment: What about `org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONArray`? How does that relate to the two options mentioned here?

Comment: @dokaspar I didn't use that library that much so cannot say

Answer (score 7):

JSONObject, as mentioned, is provided by android's API. JsonObject is specifically used for Java EE development which is essentially for web applications and networking capabilities among other things.

The reason Android does not prepackage JsonObject from Oracle Java EE package is because alot of the things javax can do, are not allowed within android like accessing the internet without permission. This means importing the entire jars files of javax would conflict with Android.

If you plan to build your own backend with Java EE, I would highly suggest using JsonObject over JSONObject. On the other hand, if you know a prebuilt rest service or something similar that supports Android's JSON even better.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use Yidong Fang's [json-simple](https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/) toolkit in order to work with JSON Objects. It provides useful functions and has no dependency on external libraries which turned out to be a huge problem during the development of Android apps.

To answer your question: If you don't want to use json-simple in you project you should use the JSONObject from org.json, because it's provided by the Android JDK. For further information see http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html.

Comment: I'm not disagreeing, just unfamiliar with this topic. What exactly do you mean by "a huge problem during the development of Android apps?" (sources appreciated). Also, why does developer.android.com use org.json if it causes problems with Android development?

Comment: Recently I found out that some packages in old Android versions do not work properly and have to get downloaded and implemented as a jar ("shadowed"). I'm not quite sure how org.json is affected by this problem, but it was very hard for me to shadow the dependencies with Gradle.

In my example "org.apache.http.conn.ssl" and bouncycastle didn't work as expected.

Comment: _Update 2019_: Please note that json simple is dead and not maintained anymore.

Answer (score -2):

1. `org.json` does not contain a parse class for parsing the JSON string. while`org.json.simple` contains a parse class.
2. `org.json.JSONObject` contains lots of getter methods to get directly as int, boolean, object, string, JSON Array, etc. `org.json.simple.JSONObject` does not contain specific methods, so you need to type cast every time while getting value of a particular key.
3. In simple words use `org.json.simple.JSONObject` for parsing alone and type cast it into `org.json.JSONObject` for further use inside the program.

Comment: `org.json` can parse a JSON string by passing it to the `JSONObject` constructor. And it sounds like you are suggesting using both libraries, which will certainly lead to confusion. Pick one and go with it.