# Convert String to javax.json.JsonValue

Tags: java

I have a `JsonObject` and I need to add new values to it. The values are Strings. There is a method available `JsonObject.put()`, which takes two variables:

1. `String` Key.
2. `JsonValue` value.

How to convert the `String`, which is in the JSON format, to `JsonValue` so that I can add it to the `JsonObject`?

Comment: you can put an object too

Comment: Thank You . . . It worked for me . :) :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

this:

```
JSONObject j=new JSONObject();
JSONObject j2=new JSONObject();
j2.put("XXX", "UUU");

j.put("one key", "one value");
j.put("2", j2);
```

Comment: I think I replied back too soon . . as it lets me give the JsonObject in the put method but then throws the UnsupoortedOperationException. And the solution you have given is for I think JSONObject which is a part of json.org and json.simple,org . . What I am working with is Javax.json.JsonObject . .

Comment: Sorry, I dont know this library. If you cant use org.json, perhaps see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26346060/javax-json-add-new-jsonnumber-to-existing-jsonobject

Comment: It's Okay . . Actually I was trying the solution given in this link only . . And it worked . .Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using `javax.json.JsonObject`, then you may try:

```
JsonArrayBuilder arrayBuilder = Json.createArrayBuilder();
for (Limit limit : limits) {
    arrayBuilder.add(Json.createObjectBuilder().add(limit.getName(), limit.getValue()));
}
JsonObject result = Json.createObjectBuilder().add("AllLimits", arrayBuilder).build();
System.out.println(result);

// ... some code before enrich existing JsonObject...
JsonObjectBuilder builder = Json.createObjectBuilder(result);
builder.add("AditionalString", Json.createValue("My Computer Game Memory Limits"));
result = builder.build();
System.out.println(result);
```

However `put(String, JsonValue)` may result in `UnsupportedOperationException` if you use `javax.json.JsonObject`.