javax.json.JSONObject.put(String,String) did working
The solution presented in Convert a string list/set to json objects in java seems not to work with javax.json.
In version 1.1.4 of the javax.json JSONObject is a subclass of the typed Map<String, JsonValue>.
Hence
    jsonObject.put("key", "value")

leads to an error, because put expects now an Json Object as the second object.
However, I did not find an easy way to convert a simple String into a JsonValue.
What is the best way to create a simple JsonValue?
Wallenstein

The question and solution you have linked are about jackson, not javax.json, why do you expect that solution to work?

javax.json.JSONObject extends Map<String, JsonValue>

So, you need to convert your String into a JsonValue.
Try this:
JsonObject jsonObject = Json.createObjectBuilder()
            .add("key", "yourValue")  // "yourValue" will be handled as a JsonValue
            .build();
System.out.println(jsonObject);


javax.json.JSONObject extends Map<String,JsonValue> since the first version. The jsonObject.put("key", "value") example uses Jackson, as Chaosfire already mentioned. Your answer is still a good solution though.

Ouch. I didn't check it. I saw the wrong object type and gave advice for a bad question. Bad in the sense of unclear. Maybe @marcinj has a better solution for the questioner.

Given that he questioner is using javax.json I think your answer is excellent. What marcinj suggest requires a different JSON library, which may require a lot of refactoring.

You are wrong in that javax.json.JsonObject has changed, this is how it always worked in its immutable way. See here for more reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26346341/471160, this is from 2014.
Since you reference a link to SO question about jackson you probably mixed code from two different libraries. If you want code like jsonObject.put("key", "value") to work then use jackson:
    // com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.13.3
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    ObjectNode jsonObject2 = mapper.createObjectNode();
    jsonObject2.put("key", "value");
    System.out.println(jsonObject2);

or org.json
    // org.json:json:20230227
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    jsonObject.put("key", "value");
    System.out.println(jsonObject);

