# How can I replicate this method to a method without the parameters?

Tags: java

I am new to java, I want to know if it's possible. But I am calling this method from another class. But the parameters are giving me a hard time. I want to call this method without having the parameters with it or have it go to the other class without any errors.

```
public List<String> getApporDb(
        String servers,
        String username,
        String password,
        Float critThreshold) throws Exception {

        try {
            //something

            try {
                // another thing
                if (serverArray != null && serverArray.length > 0 && folders != null && folders.length > 0) {

                    logger.info("inside loop of CpuUtilization and MemoryUtilization");
                    Float cpuUtilization = null;

                List<String> memoList = new ArrayList<String>();
                    for (String server : serverArray) {
                        memoList.add(server);
}
}
}
}
```

Essentially I want to get the arraylist in the middle of this method to the other class.

**The other class**

```
public void arrayList() {

databaseClass dbc = new databaseClass();
dbc.getApporDb(String servers,
        String username,
        String password);
// errors everywhere due to parameters form the line above.

}
```

Error message : Multiple markers at this line
    - appServerCpuDiskspaceutilizationMap cannot be resolved to a 
     variable
    - username cannot be resolved to a variable
    - password cannot be resolved to a variable
    - servers cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: You can't call a method without its parameters, but if you're writing the class yourself, you can overload the methods to have one with no parameters.

Comment: @Gendarme can you show me an example of overload? Please.

Comment: That's like ordering a pizza but not saying what kind of pizza, or where you want it delivered to. You're probably trying to solve a problem the wrong way here.

Comment: @Mike.Chun http://stackoverflow.com/a/9598409/5221346

Comment: @Siguza how would I call that method with the params without errors?

Comment: @Mike.Chun If you're actually writing `all the parameters` then you obviously get an error, because the JVM doesn't understand English and can't read your mind. If you wrote something else, then show us what you wrote and what the error message is and you might get some help.

Comment: The only way you can call a method that expects params without the correct number and type would be one that takes var-args (`foo(T...t)`). But that wouldn't work for your example.

Comment: @Gendarme when i said all the parameters basically the parameters that was being passed from the method. I posted it. Thank you for helping!

Comment: You need to give actual values. I suspect you're way over your head with this task and need to go back a few chapters and re-study.

Comment: You won't be able to you must pass the params

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend the class with one of your classes and then use @Override to create a new version of the method. You would then use your class as if it were the class you extended: It has the same methods and functionality, except for the methods you have overridden. 
An example could look like this:

Class a:

```
Public class A{
    public void printName(){
        System.out.println("A");
    }
    public void test(){
        System.out.println("test");
    }
}
```

Class B:

```
public class B extends A{
    @Override
    public void printName(){
        System.out.println("B");
    }
}
```

Main:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    B b = new B();
    A a = new A();
    a.printName(); -------- A
    b.printName(); -------- B
    b.test(); -------- test
    a.test(); -------- test
}
```

Comment: How would this help? Overriding wouldn't allow them to reduce the number of parameters. However, overloading would.

Answer (score 5):

In a word - no. You need to supply all the parameters when calling a method.

Comment: You can write a different version of the method without parameters, but you can't call an existing method without passing whatever parameters it requires.

Comment: @nhouser9 in order to create the loop it requires one of the params. How would I be able to replicate that?

Comment: It doesn't apply to their example but the exception to that would be `foo(T...t)`.