# How to handle changing method signature in java

Tags: java, method-signature

I'm writing a Library which has a method M() taking 3 parameters and method signature be like M(param 1, param 2, param 3) which might change during the development cycle. since this library will be used three apps A, B  and C, whenever i change the 
method signature( mostly there will change in number of parameter), Application A, B and C's existing code should not break. which is best way to handle this kind of scenario .

Comment: Have you thought about using varargs?

Comment: You need to keep the existing methods, and call the new methods from those (or vice versa).

Comment: Just add methods without removing previous. This will not break backward compatibility, but fresh clients can use fresh versions of methods. Mark previous versions with `@Deprecated` to let them know which version to use. Varargs will work only if all parameters has the same type.

Comment: use method reference from Java 8.

Comment: I think you might want to take a look at [method overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9598409/9420984)

Comment: use anonymous class :P

Comment: i have pasted structure of my code below

below interface is defined in Library

public interface MyListener extends Parcelable {

public method M( string s1, int i1, string s3);

}


//below class is defined in One of the application

class c implements MyListener {

   public method M( string s1, int i1, string s3){
   
      //method implementation will go here

   }
}

Answer (score 3):

If the signature is one way, and in use, then changing it *will* break the places it's used unless the changes are compatible with how it was used (changing `int` to `Integer`, for instance, is often compatible thanks to autoboxing).

The usual thing is to add an overload with the new signature, leaving the original method in place (although you might change its implementation). For instance, if the original was:

```
void m(Something a, SomethingElse b, YetAnotherThing c) {
    // ...
}
```

adding an overload / some overloads:

```
void m(Something a, SomethingElse b, YetAnotherThing c, ANewThing d) {
    // ...
}
// or
void m(Something a, SomethingElse b) {
    // ...
}
// or
void m(ANewThing d) {
    // ...
}
```

won't break clients using that original method (assuming the implementation continues to do what it did before, even if it does it differently).

Comment: Thanks @ T.J Crowder ..

i have  one suggestion 

can we define a POJO class and make all the parameters of the method is part of that class? like below 

in this case if i want add new  paramter just create a new member in class (MyParamClass) .

is this right approch to follow?


public class MyParamClass() {

    string s1,
    int i1;
    String s3;
}

public interface MyListener extends Parcelable {

public method M( MyParamClass obj);
}


class c implements MyListener {

   public method M( MyParamClass obj){
   }
}

Comment: @mpb - That *is* an option, but it can be a dangerous one if done naively because if you introduce a new *required* field, old code doesn't get flagged up by the compiler for not providing that field, leaving you with runtime errors instead. Using a class to hold parameters isn't necessarily problematic, but if you add a new required parameter, make the form with the new parameter a subclass of the original, and (if necessary) define an overload of `m` that takes the subclass, specifically.

Comment: Can I do the same if multiple test cases also needs change due to method signature change?

Comment: @Parthi - That's up to you and depends a lot on the details of the situation. I don't think I'd add method overloads that **only** test cases used unless it was **really** likely to be used by code in the future (but beware of YAGNI -- "You Ain't Gonna Need It"). :-) Instead, I'd update the test cases (probably; again, it depends on the details and is at least partially a matter of opinion).